# Getting namespace does not exist error for all the references added in my project

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I take the latest code from TFS and tries to build existing solution, It fails all the project building and says that : The type or namespace name 'XYZ' does not exist in the sampace 'a.b.c' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is happening with all the references and only in my system. On the other systems all these code works fine.

Can it be a Visual Studio issue or some setting which might have got changed?

Comment: Try to delete `packages` directory and then rebuild solution.

Comment: maybe you build againts other framework version then the other libs build for

Comment: thanks @dudi Keleti, it helped. now i am building with 4.5 version, it works. does that mean that i  shall check in the csproj as well so that in future it should not create problem to me or any other team member ?